# Why is the casino losing money?

Tags: probability, statistics

My friend recently went to a casino to play craps. He showed me the table and it got me thinking about odds. With my calculations below I have calculated the casino losing money, which is simply not possible..so where did I go wrong with my calculations?

FYI, I know very little about probability/stats, so my calculations/assumptions are probably completely wrong.

The craps table at the casino pays 30 to 1 for rolling 2 1's or 2 6's. I decided to calculate the odds:

- 2 Dice = 36 different rolls
- Probability of rolling two 1's: 1/36
- Probability of rolling two 6's: 1/36
- Total probability: 2/36 = 5.5%

I assume probability works better over large numbers, so let's say I bet 5$ over 100 bets.

Over 100 bets I would've spent `$500`.

However, I should've won, at least 5 times. Thats

- `$5` bet `*` `30x` multipler = `$150` per win.
- `$150` per win `*` `5` wins = `$750`.

`$750` in winnings `-` `$500` cost = `$250` (Actually cost is less since 5 of the rounds I won and it didn't cost me anything for those rounds, but for simplicity sakes)

Did I just win `$250`? Are my calculations correct?

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering what was happening to formatting...

Comment: you did not get the rules properly. if the probability to win is $1$ out of $18$ and the payoff is $30$ to $1$ it's definitely worth playing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a bet that pays $x$ to $1$ and the chances of winning are $1$ out of $y$, then in expectation you are making: 
$$+x\cdot \frac{1}{y} - 1\cdot\frac{y-1}{y}$$you have a positive expectation when the above is greater or equal to $0$, so $$\frac{x}{y} - \frac{y-1}{y} \geq 0$$ which gives $x+1 \geq y$. Using your numbers, you have $x = 30$ and $y = 18$, so it is worth it to play.

Hence,

1) Those aren't the odds and you miss read them. Or,

2) The casino is going to go bust sometime soon.

Comment: You're absolutely right :D... you can either bet on the 1's or the 6's not both, making the odds 1/36. Meaning the casino makes $96 over 100 turns... those bastards...